# Python: Compare two strings and return the longest segment that they have in common

Tags: python, string, compare, substring

As a novice in Python, I have written a working function that will compare two strings and search for the longest substring shared by both strings. For instance, when the function compares "goggle" and "google", it will identify "go" and "gle" as the two common substrings (excluding single letters), but will only return "gle" since it's the longest one.

I would like to know if anywhere part of my code can be improved/re-written, as it may be considered lengthy and convoluted.  I'll also be very glad to see other approaches to the solution.  Thanks in advance!

```
def longsub(string1, string2):
    sublist = []
    i=j=a=b=count=length=0

    while i < len(string1):
        while j < len(string2):
            if string1[i:a+1] == string2[j:b+1] and (a+1) <= len(string1) and (b+1) <= len(string2):
                a+=1
                b+=1
                count+=1
            else:
                if count > 0:
                    sublist.append(string1[i:a])
                count = 0
                j+=1
                b=j
                a=i
        j=b=0
        i+=1
        a=i

    while len(sublist) > 1:
        for each in sublist:
            if len(each) >= length:
                length = len(each)
            else:
                sublist.remove(each)

    return sublist[0]
```

Edit: Comparing "goggle" and "google" may have been a bad example, since they are equal length with longest common segments in the same positions. The actual inputs would be closer to this: "xabcdkejp" and "zkdieaboabcd". Correct output should be "abcd".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There actually happens to be a function for this in the standard library:  [`difflib.SequencMatcher.find_longest_match`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.find_longest_match)

Comment: I don't have time to write up an example now, but the docs are pretty clear.  After I get back from lunch I'll try to remember to add an example (unless someone else wants to edit one in first [*hint hint*])

Comment: It looks like `SamiN` has provided an example so I don't have to :)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: This algorithm only works when the words have the longest segment in the same indices

You can get away with only one loop. Use helper variables. Something like these (needs refactoring) http://codepad.org/qErRBPav:

```
word1 = "google"
word2 = "goggle"

longestSegment = ""
tempSegment = ""

for i in range(len(word1)):
    if word1[i] == word2[i]:
        tempSegment += word1[i]
    else: tempSegment = ""

    if len(tempSegment) > len(longestSegment):
        longestSegment = tempSegment

print longestSegment # "gle"
```

**EDIT**: mgilson's proposal of using `find_longest_match` (works for varying positions of the segments):

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

word1 = "google"
word2 = "goggle"

s = SequenceMatcher(None, word1, word2)
match = s.find_longest_match(0, len(word1), 0, len(word2))

print word1[match.a:(match.b+match.size)] # "gle"
```

Comment: thank you so much, it's so much simpler and intuitive.  thanks!

Comment: As a side note, I don't think your first solution actually works.  For example take the too words:  `'google'` and `'gleblh'`.  The longest common substring is `gle`, but I don't think your function will pick that up.

Comment: Hi Sami, what if the two strings are a little more scrambled, how would you change your code to reflect that?  sorry for not clarifying that, since that's why i resorted to slicing in my own code.

Comment: In the meantime, I suggest to take a look at the source code of `find_longest_match`.